# Swift - How to change description of current user location marker?

Tags: ios, swift, userlocation

I tried something like this:

```
var description:String = "Custom Text"
map.userLocation.description = description
```

or

```
var description:String = "Custom Text"
map.userLocation.description(description)
```

But both are wrong, I'm not sure how to do that. Moreover, Apple documentation isn't really helpful about this description method.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to? "The debugger’s print-object command invokes this method to produce a textual description of an object. 

NSObject's implementation of this method simply prints the name of the class."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `description` property of the `userLocation` property. In this context, the `description` method you're seeing is the base one inherited from `NSObject`, used when you log an object. I believe you want the `userLocation`'s `title` property.